# Alternative thought experiment of Special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers, thought-experiment

The first picture setup is used a lot in explaining special relativity.

[image]

According to the reference frame of the red person in the left space craft, the light emmited from the light source will travel vertically (the red path) to hit the reciever/mirror. While if the space craft is moving relative to a stationary green person, the green person will see that the light will take another longer path (the green path) to hit the reciever/mirror.

I will change the setup of the experiment in the next picture as following:

[image]

in the left picture, the source of light is on the head of the stationary green person while the space craft is moving to the right at speed v. The light source will send a light such that a window in the space craft will pass the light at the moment the light reaches the space craft (So the only difference is the light source is outside the space craft).

Now my question is:

Will the light hit the reciever/mirror (the green path) or won't (the red path)?

If the light will take the green path, why it bends? and if the light will take the red path (staying moving in a straight line), so why the light didn't follow the same path in the above previous experiment?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_(astronomy)

Answer (score 1):

> Will the light hit the reciever/mirror (the green path) or won't (the red path)?

The light will follow the red path and miss the receiver.

> why the light didn't follow the same path in the above previous experiment?

Because it was emitted from a different source with a different state of motion. The motion of the emitter does not affect the speed of light, but it affects the direction and frequency of the light.

Comment: So, can we say that the horizontal velocity of the ship will be the horizontal velocity of the light and hence the vertical velocity of the light will be decreased to maintain the magnitude of c?

Comment: @MohamedMostafa As viewed by the green observer in the first row of images the light has a horizontal component to its velocity. As viewed by the red observer in the second row of images the light has a horizontal component to its velocity. The speed is always c, so yes this can effect what one observed as the vertical component.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand now :)